# Yii 1 не открывать сессию

Tags: yii, сессия

При обращении через AJAX к файлу инициализируется текущая сессия, далее запускается yii-1 и перезаписывает сессию, после чего, соответственно, юзера выкидывает и ему необходимо снова авторизовываться.
Подскажите, как передать Yii текущую сессию